# Should the UV tag be blacklisted?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we get rid of the UV tag? There are already 3 UV tags UVmap, UVunwrap and UVimage. They're specific and too the point, while the UV tag doesn't really add anything.

Comment: Contrariwise, do we really need those other three tags, that are all referring to essentially the same part of the process?

Comment: Blacklisting a tag is a bit extreme at this point. If we remove it from all questions, it will automatically be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be useful for initial questions, if someone is really new to UV they might be looking for terminology rather than complete answers. Usually once someone learns terminology that opens up a new world of search terms. I say keep it as it can always be retagged to be more specific.